# Compactness of $x^4+y^4=1$

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Show $A=${$(x,y):x^4+y^4=1$} is compact. So far, I'm thinking I should mention that $0 \le x \le y-x \le 1$ and $0 \le y \le x-y \le 1$ determines the values of $(x,y)$, and since [0,1] is compact, $A$ is compact. Is this correct? On a side note, the function $f(x)=x^4+y^4-1$ should be connected as well, since $f$ is continuous and $R^2$ is connected, right?

Comment: Perhaps you might find [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) two [articles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle) interesting... :-)

Answer (score 5):

Since you are in $\mathbb{R}^2$, compactness $\iff$ closed and bounded. So all you need to do is to answer the two questions:

a) Is the set closed, i.e., does the set contain all its limit points or is the complement of this set open?

b) Is the set bounded, i.e., can the entire set be enclosed in a sufficiently big ball?

Comment: Incorrect. This only applies to $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @DonLarynx Thanks. Corrected and updated.

Comment: True, and since $A$ is a subset of $R^n$, this applies. Thank you. What about its connectedness?

Comment: @DonLarynx (The claim "compact $\iff$ closed and bounded" might apply for other metric spaces. We know it does apply for $\Bbb R^n$, but why can you be certain it is the *only* space it applies to?)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff That is true. But initially, I had it worded as "Since you are in a metric space, ..." which is obviously incorrect and that was why Don raised the alarm.

Comment: @user17762 Yes, I know. I upvoted his comment.

Comment: @Pedro: Please see the edit history.

Comment: @Pedro: I can't edit my comment. But I see what you mean.

Comment: @DonLarynx In line with Pedro's comment, what are the spaces for which compact $\iff$ closed and bounded holds true?

Comment: I would suppose those metric spaces that are isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^n$. @Pedro, can you verify this? I not know much of topology.

Comment: @user17762 You can always ask that in a new question! There is no point in letting that get lost in the comments.

Comment: Look at http://mathoverflow.net/a/36892/31729.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be given by $f(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$. Then the set $S = f([0,2 \pi])$ is compact because $f$ is continuous and $[0,1]$ is compact. Note that $S = \{(x,y) | x^2+y^2 = 1 \}$.

Now let $g:\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be given by  $g(x) = {\|x\|_2 \over \|x\|_4} x$. Note that $g$ is continuous, and if $\|x\|_2 =1$, then $\|g(x)\|_4 = 1$, that is, $g(S) = \{ (x,y) | x^4 + y^4 = 1 \}$. Since $g$ is
continuous, $g(S)$ is compact.